# postfix trying to send yahoo addresses to gmail

Tags: email, gmail, yahoo, postfix-mta

My web app's email are going through fine to gmail but failing for yahoo.  Checking the postfix log has this:

```
Jul  9 14:40:34 rose postfix/smtp[20939]: DAC0CE0009D: to=<my_address@yahoo.com>,
relay=aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.64.26]:25, delay=0.69, delays=0.13/0.01/0.44/0.11, 
dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.64.26] said: 550-5.1.1 The
email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 
double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces.
Learn more at 550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 
b5si14686142oer.37 - gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

I added the line breaks for SO readability, it was all on one line.  Any idea why it'd be trying to send an @yahoo address to google?  Seems super strange to me.

My postfix mc.conf has this at top, the rest is the default:

```
myhostname = myserver.myhost.com
myorigin = $mydomain
relayhost = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
mydestination =
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was happening because my from address was a non-existant address on my domain, which happened to be hosted by google apps.

Since my MTA was setup as a null-client, it wanted to forward the bounce message to the from address.

Yahoo was rejecting my email because my SPF record had too many DNS entries in it, which caused the (attempted) bounce message.

Strangely, even in debug mode, postfix didn't log anything more than the above line.

Comment: I have this exact problem .. how did you fix the problem exactly?